# how to attach a visualForce excel to email template

Tags: apex, visualforce, email-template

I have created an excel from a visual force page by using 
.....

it gets downloaded as .xls file.

now I want to attach this file to an email template.
how can I do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your visualforce page inside a visualforce email template like:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_attachments.htm

You can change the render type for the attachments just like in your visualforce page like this example for PDF:

```
<messaging:attachment renderAs="PDF" filename="Offerte {!relatedTo.Account.Name}.pdf">
```

Comment: I don't want pdf I want excel.

Comment: I understand. than it is:
<messaging:attachment contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#Excel.xls" cache="true">

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_sending_attachments.htm) from Salesforce where a page can be send as pdf in email attachment. Similarly you can do for Excel. Hope this helps.

```
// Reference the attachment page, pass in the account ID
PageReference pdf = Page.attachmentPDF;
pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)account.id);
pdf.setRedirect(true);

// Take the PDF content
Blob b = pdf.getContent();

// Create the email attachment
Messaging.EmailFileAttachment efa = new Messaging.EmailFileAttachment();
efa.setFileName('attachment.pdf');
efa.setBody(b);
```

Comment: it don't work for excel as contenttype="application/x-excel#FILENAME.xls". this it download the excel.